# Getting online User in Video chat Using QuickBlox

Tags: android

I am using quickblox api for video chat and i want to get online available user .I know that it can be done through roster but i don't know how to get roster and how to add entries in roster .i want this through quickblox connection and dont know how to get xmpp connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
    XMPPConnection.addConnectionCreationListener(new ConnectionCreationListener() {

        @Override
        public void connectionCreated(Connection arg0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "receive xmpp connection : " + arg0);
            connection = arg0;
            roster = arg0.getRoster();

            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            Presence presence;

            Log.e(TAG, "user count" + entries.size());

            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                Log.i(TAG, "" + entry.getUser());
                Log.i(TAG, "" + presence.getType().name());
                Log.i(TAG, "" + presence.getStatus());
            }

        }
    });
```

So at the start of your program register that XMPPConnection listener, usually it take few seconds to receive connection object.
But it will work only if you will use creatEntry only in that case rooster will see those created users.

To creat entry using Roster use next code:

```
try {
    rooster.createEntry("name", "user_id", null);
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I didn't use any group, and with success see user on second device.